# PHP Array sorting

Tags: php, sorting

Question:

```
Array
(
    [1257984000] => 2009-11-11 19:00:00
    [1258416000] => 2009-11-16 19:00:00
    [1258722000] => 2009-11-20 08:00:00
    [1258394400] => 2009-11-16 13:00:00
)
```

This is my array.  I want to sort based on the array number( ie. 1257984000,1258416000 etc).

Coding Used:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
   if ($a == $b) {
     return 0;
   }
  return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}
uasort($array, 'cmp');
```

It is not sorting properly. Whether my coding style is correct?
Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`ksort`](http://php.net/ksort) to sort by key.

Comment: uksort in his case, since he wants a comparison function.

Comment: @JW: He doesn’t need a comparison function since the default comparison of `ksort` behaves is the same as his.